# scrollBy doesn't work properly in nested recyclerview

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview

I have a vertically scrolling `RecyclerView` with horizontally scrolling inner RecyclerViews just like this.

[image: expl]

With this implementation, users can scroll each horizontal recyclerview synchronously. However, when a user scroll vertically to the parent recyclerView, a new horizontal recyclerview which has just attached on window doesn't display on same scroll x position. This is normal. Because it has just created.

So, I had tried to scroll to the scrolled position before it was displayed. Just like this:

**Note**: this is in adapter of the parent recyclerview whose orientation is vertical.

```
 @Override
    public void onViewAttachedToWindow(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder) {
        super.onViewAttachedToWindow(holder);
        CellColumnViewHolder viewHolder = (CellColumnViewHolder) holder;
        if (m_nXPosition != 0) {
             // this doesn't work properly 
             viewHolder.m_jRecyclerView.scrollBy(m_nXPosition, 0);
        }
    }
```

[image]

As you can see, `scrollBy` doesn't effect for **row 10**, **row 11**, **row 12** and **row 13** After that, I debugged the code to be able find out find out what's happening. When I set scroll position using scrollBy,  childCount() return zero for **row 10**, **row 11**, **row 12** and **row 13** So they don't scroll. But why ? and Why others work ?

- **How can I fix this ?**
- **Is onViewAttachedToWindow right place to scroll new attached recyclervViews ?**

**Note**: I have also test `scrollToPosition()`, it doesn't get any problem like this. But I can't use it at my case. Because users can scroll to the any x position which may not the exact position. So I need to set scroll position using x value instead of the position.

**Edit**: You can check [The source code](https://github.com/evrencoskun/TableViewSample)

Comment: Can you share this code in github or some other place so it's easy to debug

Comment: I have editted my question. You can check the whole code.

Comment: Why not scrolling onBind?

Comment: @natario ScrollBy doesn't work on onBind(). Because at that time, layout manager doesn't mesure/replace etc.  to the viewholders yet. However, yesterday I found a solution. I am gonna write my answer if you wonder it.

Comment: I have tried your source code on emulators running API 21, 22, 23 and 24 and I cannot replicate the problem. Where are you running the code that you see this issue? Device, emulator, API level?

Comment: @Cheticamp Because I have fixed the problem 2 day ago :)

Comment: That explains it. I would be interested in knowing what the fix was if you post the answer here.

Comment: @Cheticamp I am gonna explain my solution at the first opportunity. Thanks for spending time to my issue.

Comment: @Cheticamp You can check my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a solution that is use `scrollToPositionWithOffset` method instead using `scrollBy`. Even if both of two scroll another position, they have really different work process in back side.

For example: if you try to use `scrollBy` to scroll any pixel position and your recyclerView had not been set any adapter which means there is no any data to display and so it has no any items yet, then `scrollBy` doesn't work. RecyclerView uses its layoutManager's `scrollBy` method. So in my case, I am using `LinearLayoutManager` to the horizontal recyclerViews.

Lets see what it's doing :

```
int scrollBy(int dy, RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state) {
        if (getChildCount() == 0 || dy == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        mLayoutState.mRecycle = true;
        ensureLayoutState();
        final int layoutDirection = dy > 0 ? LayoutState.LAYOUT_END : LayoutState.LAYOUT_START;
        final int absDy = Math.abs(dy);
        updateLayoutState(layoutDirection, absDy, true, state);
        final int consumed = mLayoutState.mScrollingOffset
                + fill(recycler, mLayoutState, state, false);
        if (consumed < 0) {
            if (DEBUG) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Don't have any more elements to scroll");
            }
            return 0;
        }
        final int scrolled = absDy > consumed ? layoutDirection * consumed : dy;
        mOrientationHelper.offsetChildren(-scrolled);
        if (DEBUG) {
            Log.d(TAG, "scroll req: " + dy + " scrolled: " + scrolled);
        }
        mLayoutState.mLastScrollDelta = scrolled;
        return scrolled;
    }
```

As you can see `scrollBy` ignores the scroll intentions if there is no any child at that time.

```
  if (getChildCount() == 0 || dy == 0) {
     return 0;
  }
```

On the other hand `scrollToPosition` can work perfectly even if there is no any set data yet.

According to the [Pro RecyclerView slide](https://news.realm.io/news/360andev-yigit-boyar-pro-recyclerview-android-ui-java/), the below sample works perfectly. However you can not do that with scrollBy.

```
void onCreate(SavedInstanceState state) {
    ....
    mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(selectedPosition);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
}
```

**As a result**, I have changed little thing to use `scrollToPositionWithOffset()`.

Before this implementation I was calculating the exact scroll x position as a pixel.

After that, when the scroll came idle state, calculating the first complete visible position to the first parameter of the `scrollToPositionWithOffset()`.

For second parameter which is the offset, I am getting the value using `view.getLeft()` function which helps to get left position of this view relative to its parent.

[image]

And it works perfectly!!