# Combine scrolling of Horizontal recyclerview which is inside Vertical RecyclerAdapter

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, horizontal-scrolling

Here parent having vertical `recyclerview`  scroll and child having horizontal `recyclerview` ,I just wants to scroll all child together not individually currently child scrolling individually that’s a problem I am facing .I hope I  explained well .If anyone have some suggestion or solution please provide I shall be really thankful to you.Check attached image

[image: check attached image ,]` 
**Parent view**

```
     <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/appointments_recycler"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_10ssp"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/_10ssp">

                </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

**Adapter View containing horizontal recyclerview.**

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

            <com.app.barber.views.CustomTextView
                android:id="@+id/time_slot"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/_40ssp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/_2sdp"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/_2sdp"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/_2sdp"
                android:text="9:00 AM"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_10ssp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />


        <View
            android:layout_width="0.001sp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/color_light_grey_blue" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/days_recyclar"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/_500sdp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="visible" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You can use **[Android-Week-View](https://github.com/alamkanak/Android-Week-View)**

Comment: thanks @NileshRathod but i have some custom views thats why i a m not using this as you suggest .

Comment: I got solution from this https://github.com/Stoyicker/AligningRecyclerView?utm_source=android-arsenal.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=2801

Comment: did you find any answer? this is my question too.

Comment: Have you checked above answer link .you can use that or  you can go  with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44819583/scrollby-doesnt-work-properly-in-nested-recyclerview